# Can a module use 'ref' sections on ARM?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I have a module that contains functions with a `ref` attribute.  This places the `.text` in a different section.  The way the [ARM stack frame unwinding](https://wiki.linaro.org/KenWerner/Sandbox/libunwind?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=libunwind-LDS.pdf) works is that two additional sections are placed in an **ELF** file.  These *sections* provide tables to the ARM [unwind.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/unwind.c).  The [module.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/module.c) file populates these tables when loading a module.

When using the `.ref.text` section, the two sections `.ARM.extab.ref.text` and `.ARM.exidx.ref.text` are created by gcc-4.7 to allow unwinding of this code. Unfortunately, **module.c** only scans for `.init`, `.devinit`, etc and does not add these sections.  If we turn on **CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK**, and a `__ref` frame is active during an allocation, the stack trace code give many *unwind: Index not found* messages in the kernel logs.

1. Is it wrong to use `__ref` in a module?
2. Should there by *architechure* linker files for the ARM that place the `.ref` *extab* and *exidx* in the core *.ARM.extab* and *.ARM.exidx* sections?
3. Why am I the only one to see this?  I have 2.6.36, but the problem seems to exist in the mainline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [*68k*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/m68k/kernel/module.lds) and the [*ia64*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/ia64/module.lds) have additional linker files, with the *ia64* fitting the ARM `__ref` requirements.

Adding the following to *arch/arm/Makefile*,

```
# Glob 'ref' unwind tables.
KBUILD_LDFLAGS_MODULE += -T $(srctree)/arch/arm/module.lds
```

And *arch/arm/modules.lds* as,

```
SECTIONS {
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.ARM.exidx.exit.text)
        *(.ARM.extab.exit.text)
        *(.ARM.exidx.devexit.text)
        *(.ARM.extab.devexit.text)
    }
    /* Group unwind sections together: */
    .ARM.extab : { *(.ARM.extab*) }
    .ARM.exidx : { *(.ARM.exidx*) }
    .text : { *(.text); *(.ref.text); *(.rodata*); }
}
```

will put the `__ref` annotations *unwind* information together with normal *unwind* code.

This may solve multiple *unwind: Index not found* kernel log messages when using **modules** on ARM Linux.  The `/DISCARD/` portion is not needed on with a newer [module.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/module.c) as it supports module `.exit` unwind info; but it is useful for 2.6.36 where this information is newer used.

This may cause other issues and hasn't been run past the ARM Linux mailing list to be vetted for issues.

Comment: +1 Nice research.  It does seem like it might be a good idea to run it by the relevant folks before adopting it for more than experimental use though.